# R plm time fixed effect model

Tags: r, plm

I found these sample codes online on fixed effect model:

Code 1

```
fixed.time <- plm(y ~ x1 + factor(year), data=Panel, index=c("country", "year"), model="within")
```

Code 2

```
fixed.time <- plm(y ~ x1, data=Panel, index=c("country", "year"), model="within")
```

What is the difference? Doesn't index with country,year mean the fixed effect model actually create a dummy variable for year?
The documentation does not explain this very clearly.

Comment: sorry i cant edit but code 1 has a effect="time" and code 2 does not have an effect

Answer (score 6):

In `plm`, specifying the `index` arguments just formats the data. You want to look at the `effect` argument, which indicates whether to use *individual* (the first index you provided), *time* (the second), or *twoways* (both) effects.  If you don't specify anything, *individual* is the default.

So in your first regression, you (implicitly) used *individual*, and added time effects yourself. This is equivalent to using *twoways*. See code below.

```r
library(plm)
#> Loading required package: Formula
Panel <- data.frame(y <-  rnorm(120), x1 = rnorm(120), 
                    country = rep(LETTERS[1:20], each = 6),
                    year = rep(1:6, 20))
## this computes just individual FE
mod2 <- plm(y ~ x1, data=Panel, index=c("country", "year"), model="within")

## this computes individual FE, and you added time FE:
fixed.time <- plm(y ~ x1 + factor(year), data=Panel, index=c("country", "year"), model="within")

## this computes individual and time FE
mod3 <- plm(y ~ x1, data=Panel, index=c("country", "year"), model="within", effect = "twoways")

## second and third model should be identical:
all.equal(coef(fixed.time)["x1"], coef(mod3)["x1"])
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>